# Migration code to Quartz job is not working (because needs session scoped beans)

Tags: java, spring, grails, vaadin, quartz-scheduler

I migrated a code to run asynchronously, in a Quartz job.

Now I'm getting this error when I try to use a session scoped view, called when the quartz job finishes:

> org.quartz.JobExecutionException:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.vaadinView': Scope 'session' is
> not active for the current thread
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.vaadinView'

My bean is:

```
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public class VaadinView implements View, DisposableBean
```

I know that the Quartz job runs on another thread, an the session context is lost. So, before calling the job I'm storing the request attributes in the job itself

`RequestAttributes attributes = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();`

Then, before calling the session scoped bean, I'm restoring the request attributes:

```
RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(attributes); // workaround
vaadinView.doSomethingOnUI(); // error here
```

The problem is that now a have the same error, but with another message, telling me that the session is required:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Session must not be null
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:134)
        at org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils.getSessionMutex(WebUtils.java:403)
        at org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes.getSessionMutex(ServletRequestAttributes.java:253)
        at org.springframework.web.context.request.SessionScope.get(SessionScope.java:91)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:346)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:192)
```

My question is: how can I use the quartz job thread to update the UI

Note: I'm using Grails + Vaadin + SpringBoot

Comment: This feels wrong.  A job should not depend on a view. And most likely
not the other way around. You might better off decoupling things with
e.g. a pub/sub or some queue, where both your workers and the views do
what they do best.  E.g. the worker notify about the successful task and
the view can update the user via UI.access/Push.

Comment: maybe @Async methods annotation can help you instead of quartz https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/